# MySQL server check constraint with range

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to understand how to properly use the **check** constraint, but it keeps on failing when i use ranges;

```
mysql> create table test( code varchar(64), constraint ctr check (code like '[0-9]%')) :
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec) 
-- Allow strings that starts with a number, but when i try to insert '5foo' for example:
```

```
mysql> insert into test (code) values ('5foo' ) ;
ERROR 3819 (HY000) : Check constraint 'ctr' is violated.
```

Never the less using a *normal* check constraint works just fine, for example :

```
mysql> create table test( code varchar(64), constraint ctr check(code like '_foo_bar%'));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

```
mysql> insert into test (code) values ('5foo0barabc');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
```

```
mysql> insert into test (code) values ('55foo0barabc');
ERROR 3819 (HY000): Check constraint 'test_chk_1' is violated.
```

as you can see.

I would like to understand why it's not working, and if ranges just aren't a thing in mySQL (because i read that the check constraint it self wasn't part of it earlier before, im using *Ver 8.0.28 for macos11 on arm64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)* btw if it's of any cause) is there a way to achieve the following check (which is what im **actually** trying to achieve, the upper code is just an example): `([A-Z][0-9]{9})` a string that starts with an uppercase letter and is followed by 9 numbers.

Thank you guys in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL (and standard SQL) does not support character ranges in the `LIKE` predicate. The only pattern metacharacters supported by `LIKE` are `%` and `_` (and I suppose `\` to escape the other metacharacters).

Microsoft SQL Server implements character ranges for `LIKE`, but this is their own custom extension to standard SQL.

For MySQL, you need to use `REGEXP` instead of `LIKE`. But then `%` is not a pattern-matching character. Use the regular expression equivalent `.*` instead, or else just leave that part out, because regular expressions implicitly allow any characters to follow your pattern. Also, for a regular expression you need to use `^` to make pattern match the start of the string, otherwise it will match if it matches any substring within.

Example:

```
create table test( code varchar(64), constraint ctr check (code regexp '^[0-9].*'))
```

Alternative:

```
create table test( code varchar(64), constraint ctr check (code regexp '^[0-9]'))
```

Comment: Thank you !, ```'^([A-Z][0-9]{9})'``` achieves what i want with a char(10).